# find the position of string in pdf file

Tags: objective-c, ios

i try to find the byte location of string in pdf file
but it not give me the true value

```
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"]];

    int count =0;
    int ref=0;
    int gh=0;

// array contains all the line in th epdf
 NSArray *array = [string2 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    for ( NSString *libe in array) {

        ref++;



         count=count+[libe lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 if ([@"my string" isEqualToString:libe])
        {



            id objet1 = [array objectAtIndex:ref];

            NSString *val1=(NSString*)objet1;


            NSRange range = [val1 rangeOfString:@"mystring" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
total =count+range.location;

}

}
```

Comment: You should really say what value it gives and what you expected. However, PDF files are not raw text. You can't load them into a string. Use `NSData` to load the file and `-rangeOfData:options:range:` to search it for a byte sequence (which is not the same a string, although may be the same as a string **in a specific encoding**).

Comment: but i want find the location of string not search the string

Comment: And that's what I wrote about. You need to load the PDF file into an `NSData` and search within that using `-rangeOfData:options:range:` for the byte sequence corresponding to the string you're looking for in some particular encoding. I have no idea what encoding you can expect to find within a binary PDF file, though.

Comment: NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    
    
    NSRange range = [string2 rangeOfString:@"Mystring" options:NSForcedOrderingSearch];
    
    NSLog(@"pos est %u",range.location+range.length);

Comment: I very much doubt that will work reliably. You can't reliably create an `NSString` from a PDF file. PDF files are not pure text.

Comment: you know i try to find the ByteArrange in pdf and i can get the value